# React nested routing not working while the code looks correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router on React, and want to try nested routing.
According to the documents and many other websites, the following code works properly, but it doesn't.

**Index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**App.js**

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header  />
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path={`/Account`}
              render={() => (
                <Account {...this.state} onConnect={this.onConnect} />
              )}
            />
          ... and other Routes
          </Switch>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```

**Header.js**

```
return (
<Link to="/Account" className="ml1 no-underline black">
  Account
</Link>

.... and other links
```

**Account.js**

```
return (
<div>
  <Link to={`${url}`} component="button">
    AccountContent
  </Link>
  <Link to={`${url}/ComponentA`} component="button">
    ComponentA
  </Link>
  <Link to={`${url}/ComponentB`} component="button">
    ComponentB
  </Link>
  　
</div>
<Switch>
  <Route
    path={`${path}`}
    render={() => (
      <AccountContent  />
    )}
  />
  <Route
    path={`${path}/ComponentA`}
    render={() => (
      <ComponentA  />
    )}
  />
  <Route
    path={`${path}/ComponentB`}
    render={() => (
      <ComponentB  />
    )}
  />
</Switch>
);
```

The issue I'm facing here is that The router in the Account is not working.
Can anybody help me to solve this issue?

NOTE: Of course the code above has proper importing.

Comment: Do you have any error on the console? Or just simply not loading the `/Account` route into your browser's URL section.

Comment: No, I don't have any errors. ```  <AccountContent> ``` in the ```/Account``` is loaded, but cannot switch to others.